# Spring Security get user info in rest service, for authenticated and not authenticated users

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, jhipster

I have a spring rest service, I want to use it for authenticated and not authenticated users. And I want to get user information from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` if user is authenticated.

- If I use
  `.antMatchers("/app/rest/question/useroperation/list/**").permitAll()`
  in ouath2 configuration like below, then I can get user info for
  authenticated user, but 401 error for not authenticated users.
- If I
  `.antMatchers("/app/rest/question/useroperation/list/**").permitAll()`
  and ignore the url in WebSecurity by
  `web.ignoring()..antMatchers("/app/rest/question/useroperation/list/**")`
  in `SecurityConfiguration` like below, then all users can call the
  service, but I cant get user information from SecurityContext.

How can configure my spring security to call a url for authenticated and not authenticated users and get user info from SecurityContext if user logged in.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Inject
    private AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
                .disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/views/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/rest/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/rest/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/rest/question/useroperation/list/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/rest/question/useroperation/comment/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/app/rest/question/useroperation/answer/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/app/rest/question/definition/**").hasAnyAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/app/rest/logs/**").hasAnyAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/websocket/tracker").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/websocket/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/metrics/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/health/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/dump/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/shutdown/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/beans/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/info/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/autoconfig/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/env/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/trace/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated();

    }

}
```

SecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/fonts/**")
            .antMatchers("/images/**")
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**")
            .antMatchers("/styles/**")
            .antMatchers("/views/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/rest/register")
            .antMatchers("/app/rest/activate")
            .antMatchers("/app/rest/question/useroperation/list/**")
            .antMatchers("/console/**");
    }


    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
            return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`permitAll()` still requires `Authentication` object to present in `SecurityContext`.

For not oauth users this can be achieved with anonymous access enabled:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
//some configuration
     .and()
        .anonymous() //allow anonymous access
     .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/views/**").permitAll()
//other security settings
```

Anonymous access will add additional filter: `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` to the filter chain that populate `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` as Authentication information in case no `Authentication` object in `SecurityContext`

Answer (score 0):

I've this security config for check AuthUser by `/public/auth`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/api/skills/**", "/api/profile/**", "/api/info/**").authenticated()
           .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority(Role.ROLE_ADMIN.getAuthority())
           .antMatchers("/public/auth").permitAll()
           .and().httpBasic()
           .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
           .and().csrf().disable();
}

@GetMapping(value = "/public/auth")
private ResponseEntity<User> getAuthUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthUser authUser) {
    return authUser == null ? 
               ResponseEntity.notFound().build() :
               ResponseEntity.ok(authUser.getUser());
}
```