# Enable Spring security by specific route

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

How i can enable Spring security for some routes. For examle:
i have web site with content by different routes which started from 
`'/**'`. In this routes i need disable spring security.
But i have another web module
`/admin-panel/**` where  i must enable spring security.

So, my security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin-panel").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Comment: with `permitAll()` you are disabling the authentication, `.antMatchers("/admin-panel").hasRole('ADMIN')` should work, it will check if the user has ADMIN role or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
http.
    .anonymous()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin-panel/**").authenticated()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
```

Anonymous access will add additional filter: AnonymousAuthenticationFilter to the filter chain that populate AnonymousAuthenticationToken as Authentication information in case no Authentication object in SecurityContext.

Referred to, [Spring Security get user info in rest service, for authenticated and not authenticated users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230861/spring-security-get-user-info-in-rest-service-for-authenticated-and-not-authent/25280897#25280897)