# How to secure anonymous access restricted by ip address in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'd like to allow anonymous access, restricted to a particular IP address subnet, to a URL.

The URL is :

http://10.102.34.98:880/auth/tokens/revoke/blabla where auth is the context root of the web-app.

The accessing IP address is 10.102.34.98
The subnet mask of the accessing IP address is 255.255.255.0
The trusted.client.subnet property is set to 10.102.34.0/24

Anonymous access works fine:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize","/tokens/revoke/**")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/tokens/revoke/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
}
```

but as soon as I replace the  `permitAll()` with  `hasIpAddress()` I get redirected to my login page.

How can I allow anonymous access restricted by IP address subnet?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize","/tokens/revoke/**")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests() 
            .antMatchers("/tokens/revoke/**").hasIpAddress(environment.getProperty("trusted.client.subnet"))
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
}
```

Update 1:

It's this code at the end that is forcing the login form to be displayed. I was hoping it wouldn't take this into accont as well as it had passed the IP address whitelisting.

```
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll();
```

Comment: What URL do you call?

Comment: /tokens/revoke/blabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get more info by enabling the Spring Security logs:

```
-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE
```

Most likely, what is happening is that, one `hasIpAddress` matches, the role `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` is given to the user making the request. And that role is not enabled unless `anonymous()` is enabled in your security configuration.

See these other questions:

- [Spring Security get user info in rest service, for authenticated and not authenticated users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230861/spring-security-get-user-info-in-rest-service-for-authenticated-and-not-authent/25280897#25280897)
- [Spring Security permitAll() not allowing anonymous access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696717/spring-security-permitall-not-allowing-anonymous-access)