# Jhipster + PertmitAll on microservice

Tags: spring-security, jhipster

I have a jhipster microsrvice and gateway App set up. 
Its a search application that I am trying to build. 
For this, I do not need user to be authenticated on every request.

So, for this I am trying add following line to securityConfiguration of gatewayApp.

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
```

but I get exception with message :

```
message" : "Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.ribbonPing
```

I tried with `antMatchers("fruitservicev1/api/**").permitAll()`, where fruitservicev1 is the name of my service app.

I also tried to change   .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated() to  .antMatchers("/api/**").pertmitAll(); in MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration of service App.

Still gets the same exception.

the only thing that works is  : `.antMatchers("fruitservicev1/api/cities").permitAll()` in secturityConfiguration of gateway app.

but with this, I would have to add each url in this file. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem comes from the **order** you wrote the permission in your configuration. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31792102/8800147