# I put basic authentication in spring boot but how we access some Api without authentication login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As per the title I put some basic authentication in spring boot but how we access some API without authentication login

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31792102/4214241

Answer (score 0):

```
http.ignoring().antMatchers("/authFailure");
```

We can use like the above to ignore specific URL paths.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767205/spring-security-exclude-url-patterns-in-security-annotation-configurartion) out.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the APIs and permit for all without authentication

Example

> .antMatchers(GET, "/home","/health").permitAll()

This will allow GET request on 2 endpoints for all requests, even without authentication

Complete sample

```
   http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(GET, "/home","/health").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
```

Note : It takes ordering to account